# Python D-Bus and Tkinter main loop integration

Tags: python, tkinter, dbus

I have a Python app that uses Tkinter GUI and Twisted. Twisted has support for a Tkinter main loop, so the two are working together nicely.

Now I'd like to add some D-Bus code into the app. But looking at the docs, I can't see how to integrate D-Bus into the Tkinter main loop. The [Python D-Bus tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#setting-up-an-event-loop) says it has main loop support for:

- glib main loop
- Qt main loop

What would be involved in making Python D-Bus work with a Tkinter main loop?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise it, but there are [several D-Bus bindings for Python](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/) besides `python-dbus` which is called the "reference implementation".

One is a [D-Bus binding for Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txdbus). I've tried the [usage example](https://github.com/cocagne/txdbus#usage-example) (minus the `reactor.stop()` call), and it worked fine in my app.

There is also some work being done on generalising Python event loops, in [PEP 3156](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/) `asyncio`. This will hopefully simplify things in future, once various Python frameworks add support for `asyncio` style event loops.

- [PEP 3156 for TKinter proposal](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/21)
- [python-dbusx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dbusx) — D-Bus for PEP 3156

Comment: Regardless of this answer, I'm still interested to know how `python-dbus` could integrate into the Tkinter main loop.